# Natural and Real sets of numbers, which one is bigger than another?

Tags: natural-numbers, real-numbers, integers

From the years ago, it has always been this question in my mind which a teacher of high school talked about in a class but I never found it's correct answer.

We have set of natural numbers ${1,2,3,4,5,...}$ and set of real numbers.

We have two concepts to prove that these sets of numbers are equal or smaller than each other.

### Concept 1

If we choose any number from the natural numbers, we can choose a number from real set of number, so they are equal.

### Concept 2

Natural numbers are subset of the real numbers, so natural numbers set is smaller than set of real numbers.

Which concept is correct?

Comment: Neither. Can you form a bijection from the reals to the natural?

Comment: @PepperSausage what do you mean by bijection?

Comment: This is a famous question. Maybe try reading at this link and searching on mathSE a little. There have been many questions on this. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent It can be proved that for a list of real numbers, where they have a specific place in the sequence (e.g. $2.5$ is $1^{st}$, $\pi$ is $2^{nd}$, etc.) there will be a real number missing from the list. This is roughly what PepperSausage means by making a bijection between them. So there are more real numbers than natural numbers.

Comment: @enthusiasticstudent: One being a subset of the other isn't enough to guarantee a difference in size. Think about, say, all multiples of three. They constitute a proper subset of the natural numbers, but there's as many of them as there are natural numbers!

Comment: Surely you can see that Concept 1 is rubbish? The reasoning behind Concept 2 is also false, but not so obviously.

Comment: @TonyK: Concept 1 appears to be what Cantor's Diagonal Argument refutes. Concept 2 works so well for finite sets, so maybe it *is* somewhat subtle, I don't really know anymore :) After all one gets so used to these concepts.

Comment: @String: Concept 1 says that if $|A| \le |B|$, then $|A| = |B|$. It doesn't take Cantor's diagonal argument to refute that.

Comment: @TonyK: I get your drift! However the OP seems to imagine that we can easily construct an enumeration of the real numbers by the natural numbers. And *that* is what Cantor refutes.

Answer (score 6):

The renown [Cantor's Diagonal Argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument) shows that although we can easily map the set of natural numbers to the set of real numbers in many ingenious ways, we can never find a surjection $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb R$. A surjection here means $f(\mathbb N)=\mathbb R$. Instead, as Cantor proved, we can do no better than $f(\mathbb N)\subset\mathbb R$.

This means that any counting function $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb R$ assigning enumerations to the real numbers such that the real numbers can be written as a list $\mathbb R=\{f(1),f(2),...\}$ is impossible. The set $\{f(1),f(2),...\}$ can contain **some** of the real numbers, but not **all**.

In this sense, which is called **cardinality** (see link in comments), the set of real numbers is bigger.

---

There are various proofs of Cantor's Diagonal Argument. One is to prove the more general statement that given a set $A$, the so-called [Power Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) $\mathcal P(A)$ containing all subsets of $A$ always has bigger cardinality than $A$.

So assume we have found an enumeration $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. Then $f(n)$ is some subset of $\mathbb N$ as for instance $\{2,4,6,8,...\}$. If $f$ were surjective it should be possible for any element $B\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ to find some $b\in \mathbb N$ with $f(b)=B$.

Consider $B\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ defined as
$$
B=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\notin f(n)\}
$$
Assume we have found $b$ such that $f(b)=B$. Suppose $b\in B=f(b)$, but then the above definition implies that $b$ should not be an element of $B$. So we must have $b\notin B=f(b)$, but then the above definition tells us that $b$ should be in $B$. Contradiction! For any function $f$ the set $B$ above is well defined, but as just shown no element of $\mathbb N$ can map to it. We must have $f(\mathbb N)\subset\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus B$, so in particular $f(\mathbb N)\neq\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ for **any** choice of $f$.

---

Let us connect the above argument to the real numbers. We can make a simple mapping $g:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ that takes a given subset of $B=\{n_1,n_2,...\}\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ of natural numbers and maps it to
$$
g(B)=10^{-n_1}+10^{-n_2}+...=\sum_{n\in B}10^{-n}
$$
For instance $B=\{2,4,6,8,...\}$ would map to $g(B)=0.010101\overline{01}$. This mapping is injective meaning that different sets $B$ map to different real numbers $g(b)$. So $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ has the same cardinality as the subset $g(\mathcal P(\mathbb N))$ of the real numbers meaning that we have the cardinality inequalities
$$
|\mathbb N|<|\mathcal P(\mathbb N)|=|g(\mathcal P(\mathbb N))|\leq|\mathbb R|
$$
In fact a different choice of $g$ shows that $|\mathcal P(\mathbb N)|=|\mathbb R|$, but that is a different story.