# Wouldn't real set be indeed smaller rather than bigger than the integer set?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, integers

This is linked to [Natural and Real sets of numbers, which one is bigger than another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910194/natural-and-real-sets-of-numbers-which-one-is-bigger-than-another) but clearly my question is of a different nature.

Hello there,

### I would like to ask the community a question : Why is it that one say that "real" are "bigger" than "integer" ??

---

Now i'm well aware of the diagonal argument, but it seems to me that there is no logical connection to bigger, and even that the real set is indeed smaller than the integer set. I'll try to explain, using only logical arguments, because i don't know much about mathematics, but i hope that by using logic i'll be able to communicate with the mathematical community and be able to grasp what's wrong in my understanding.

---

I would like to try to define a few words i'll be using first :
Let's assume that there exists a turing complete language L, that you can write programs with, such that the program can process a finite string, and produce another finite string, and has a terminal instruction (ie programs can terminate).

Then let's call Program, something written in L, that take as input an integer (let's say as a finite string of 0/1), and output either 0 or 1 (but has no guarantee to terminate).
Let's call "List" a program that take as input an integer, and output a finite string, and is guaranteed to terminate for any integer input.
Let's call "Subpart of the Integer set" (shorten as SI) a Program that somehow is guaranteed to terminate for any integer input. (So any SI is both a List and and a program)

Let's call maximal List (of a criterion C), a list (if there exists one) that given the criterion C list all output string that meets C.

---

So now we can say that there is indeed a maximal list of Programs (trivial to explicit), and that there is no maximal List of SI (because if there was, then you'd be able to have a program that answer the termination problem for any input).

Now, there is another way of noticing that there is no maximal List of SI, and that is to apply the "diagonal strategy".

Let's presume that there exist an explicit List of all SI called List_SI, then you can build a new SI :
new_SI (n) :
- let a = List_SI (n) (n). If a = 0 return 1, else return 0;
new_SI is in 0/1 and terminate, so it is definitely a SI.

Now, this look to me as exactly the diagonal argument used by Cantor, wich enable to conclude that "Real Set" is "Bigger" than "Integer Set".
Only we replaced the real set with the list of programs that represents a subpart of N, and the integer set with a generalization to programs that represents a subpart of N but might leave some integer neither into or out of the the subpart it represents.

Thus, we have to conclude that the Program that terminate Set (SI) is Bigger than the set of all programs (Program). Wich seems a bit counter intuitive to me. Indeed i would tend to assume that the set of program that terminate is indeed smaller.

---

And there i am, asking the mathematical community : wouldn't be the "real set" indeed be "smaller" than the "integer set" ?

Comment: Didn't read, but the answer is no.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Just the fact that integers are contained in the reals means that the set of reals can not be 'smaller'.

Comment: Did read, made no sense, and Pedro is correct. One problem: You define "maximal list" for criteria on natural numbers, but apply it to criteria on programs, where the definition does not work.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff If we argue like this? We know that every integer is a real number. But $0.5$ is a real. So, $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What you have shown is simply that there is no List of SI. In other words, the halting program (a program whose outputs are all terminating programs) does not exist. Then? What has this in common with comparing two collections of programs?

Comment: There are some List of SI, as per my comment on your answer. ( [ returning [the program that return "0" for any input], for any input ] is such a list.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry: I will use the word "program" in its correct meaning, i.e. something having as an input a number and as an output a number, or it does not terminate.

I recall you the notion of *recursively enumerable* set: a subset $A \subseteq \Bbb{N}$ is recursively enumerable if there exists a program $L(n)$ such that
$$\{ L(n): n \in \Bbb{N} \} = A$$

It is true that you can list all programs: this gives you a universal list $U(n)$ listing all programs. In particular
$$\{ n \in \Bbb{N} : U(n) \mbox{ is a program} \} = \Bbb{N}$$
is recursively enumerable.

Now, what you have proved is that
$$\{ n \in \Bbb{N} : U(n) \mbox{ is a SI (i.e. it always terminates with $0$ or $1$)} \}$$
is not recursively enumerable. This is an important result in computability theory, due to Turing himself.

Despite being recursively enumerable, $\Bbb{N}$ has some non recursively enumerable subsets. But this does not mean that the collection of SI is bigger than the collection of programs. Not at all.

This result means that you can list all programs, but you have totally no way of *deciding* which one of them is a SI and which one isn't. So, in particular, there is no way to ensure that a program is a list (this is referred to your sentence "is guaranteed to terminate for any integer input": you cannot have a guarantee).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your clear answer.   From your answer, i then assume that there exists an injective function from programs that terminate to N.  So that it is not possible to state that "Program that terminate are uncountable" Is that accurate ?  If "program that terminate are uncountable", then wouldn't that mean that clearly Program that terminate are bigger than N, in exactly the same way that R is bigger than N ?

Comment: There indeed is a way to guarantee that a program is a List. For example, the list of all string "0", is indeed a List.  The sub list of all programs, that has a binary representation that does not begin with 0 (given any way to normalize programs to a binary representation in a unique way), is indeed also a List.

Comment: This has nothing to deal with countability or uncountability. Here we are talking about listability by a program (or, equivalently, recursively enumerability). Indeed here everything is always countable (in terms of bijection with $\Bbb{N}$). Moreover, it is not true that "being the zero list" is decidable: actually the set $\{ n: U(n)(k) =0 \mbox{ for all } k \}$ is not recursively enumerable.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, but here is the program that corresponds, and i'm sure that it does terminate (so i expect it to be recursively enumerable) .   [ return [ return 0 ]]

Comment: "Indeed everything is always countable", that is to say, it is obvious and trivial to find an explicit injection of a non recursively enumerable set [ex : program that do terminate]. I can accept that this a trivial for a mathematician, but i can't imagine what such an injection actually looks like. Would you be so kind as to provide one ?

Comment: Well of course one could argue thus : let's give all program a number, and then only "keep" magically the numbers of the program that actually terminate, then here is your injection.  I guess. Although i wouldn't call that an explicit injection, in that we don't even know what the input set actually is. It is undefined.